# Noahide & Zera Yisrael?

Tags: halacha, noachide-laws

Is there any prohibition (Torah or rabbinical) against a Noahide man having relations or even marrying a Zera Yisrael woman who is not halachically Jewish?

For the hypothetical case here, the woman was raised in a reform community, and her grandmother's conversion was likely halachically invalid. If the grandmother does not have a valid conversion, then her daughters and granddaughters would be Zera Yisrael and not halachically Jewish.

Therefore the question then arises, is a Zera Yisrael woman permitted to a Noahide man?

Also, what level of due diligence is a Noahide required to perform when confirming a woman's claim that her grandmothers conversion was not valid? In the mouths of two or more let a thing be established?

Comment: Was the grandfather Jewish? If not, then his descendants aren't Zera Yisrael.

Comment: Hariel, grandfather in this scenario is presumed to be halachically Jewish

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Comment: You're asking two different questions here- a) are there any restrictions on Bnei Noach marrying Zera Yisrarel?and b) what level of responsibility does a Ben Noach bear to ensure his wife is not Jewish? These are great questions! But ask them separately

Comment: Why should there be any restrictions on "Bnei Noach" marrying the so-called "Zera Yisrael"? They are both halachically considered as non-Jews.

Comment: A Jewish Grandfather doesn't make a child Zera Yisrael.